# Canvas : Make a drawImage of a video

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-canvas

I wrote this code that brings me to a particular problem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #video {width: auto;}
        #viewfinder {position: absolute; border: solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 5px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
 
    <video id="video" autoplay></video>
    <div id="viewfinder"></div>
    <button id="snap">Scan</button>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
 
var video = document.getElementById('video');  
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
 
// Get access to the camera
if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
 
        // Wait until the video is loaded
        video.addEventListener( "loadedmetadata", function (e) {
 
            var viewfinder = document.getElementById('viewfinder');
            var video_height = video.offsetHeight;
            var video_width = video.offsetWidth;
 
            vis_dim = Math.min(video_height, video_width);
 
            // Find the width of the viewfinder's borders
            border_wdt = window.getComputedStyle(viewfinder).getPropertyValue("border-left-width");
          
            // The borders are assumed to be smaller than 10px
            border_wdt = parseInt(border_wdt[0]);
 
            // Create the viewfinder
            viewfinder.style.height = vis_dim - vis_dim / 10 + "px";
            viewfinder.style.width = vis_dim - vis_dim / 10 + "px";
 
            // Add some variables about the viewfinder
            var vf_height = viewfinder.offsetHeight;
            var vf_width = viewfinder.offsetWidth;
 
            viewfinder.style.top = video.offsetTop + ((video_height - vf_height) / 2) + "px";
            viewfinder.style.left = video.offsetLeft + ((video_width - vf_width) / 2) + "px";
 
            // Create the canvas
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.id = "canvas";
            canvas.width = vf_height - border_wdt * 2;
            canvas.height = vf_height - border_wdt * 2;
            canvas.style.border = "1px solid";
             
            // Insert the canvas in the body
            var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
            body.appendChild(canvas);
 
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 
            // When the snap is click :
            document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
 
                // Copy viewfinder's view on the canvas
                context.drawImage(
                                    // element to copy
                                    video,
 
                                    // Begin off the zone to copy: left
                                    viewfinder.offsetLeft + border_wdt - video.offsetLeft,
 
                                    // Begin off the zone to copy: top
                                    viewfinder.offsetTop + border_wdt - video.offsetTop,
 
                                    // Width of the zone to copy
                                    vf_width - border_wdt * 2,
 
                                    // Height of the zone to copy
                                    vf_width - border_wdt * 2,
 
                                    // Left point to begin the copy in the canvas
                                    0,
 
                                    // Top point to begin the copy in the canvas
                                    0,
 
                                    // Copy width
                                    vf_width - border_wdt * 2,
 
                                    // Copy height
                                    vf_width - border_wdt * 2
                                );
            });
        }, false );
    });
}
 
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

This code allows me to make a screenshot of my camera's video on a small area I will have defined (I named it viewfinder).

It works very well until I decide to change the width or height of my video in css. An area that has nothing to do with the viewfinder is paint in the canvas.

Has anyone ever had to deal with this kind of problem? Took 2s to test the code if my explanations are not clear :)

Thank you in advance